# Poor Magento performance on AWS ARM

Tags: magento2, aws, magento2.4.6, amazon

I'm using Magento Open source 2.4.6.

And I just switched from AWS x86 t2.small ubuntu to AWS ARM a1.medium/2GB and the performance is terrible(very slow speed) compared to the t2.

Is there anything to be done to speed up this setup? Or do I have to do the painful switch back.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions for better speed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new x86 t2.small instance again so solve the performance issue..